# Laravel validation couldn't store value after validate and give error 500

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I have a form that using ajax for update data client. In that form there is an input file. Everything is going fine except for updating the file. File is sent, it changed on storage too, but it gives error on validation and didn't change data on database.
Here is the code on the controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
    {
        $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'logo'=> 'image|file|max:100',
            'level' => 'required|max:1' 
        ]);

        $validatedData['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        
        if ($validatedData->fails()){
            return response()->json($validatedData->errors());
        } else {

            if($request->file('logo')){
                if($request->oldLogo){
                    Storage::delete($request->oldLogo);
                }
                $validatedData['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store('logo-clients');
            }
            $validateFix = $validatedData->validate();
            
            Client::where('id', $client->id)->update($validateFix);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'Success!'
            ]);
        } 
    }
```

It gives error on line :

```
$validatedData['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store('logo-clients');
```

With message :
"Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Validation\Validator as array"

I use the same code that works on another case, the difference is the other not using ajax or I didn't use Validator::make on file input. I guess it's just wrong syntax but I don't really know where and what it is.

Comment: `Validator::make` returns a Validator instance, not an array of data

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the validated input of a `Validator`, use the `validated()` function like so:

```php
$validated = $validator->validated();
```

Docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators
- https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Validator.html

Comment: Yes, I already did that, you can see after the line that gives the error as I mentioned above, I even changed the validated() to validate() to check if it is a typo. But I don't think that's the case, because the code stops before even reaching that line.

Comment: 1- `$validator = Validator::make(...` 2- `$validatedData = $validator->validated()` afaik if it fails will return the errors to as response, so u dont need to return them. so after step 2, the data is validated, otherwise, next lines after it aren't reached

Comment: Idk, but i end up split the validation data into two,
It works tho..

Answer (score 0):

$validatedData is an object of type Illuminate\Validation\Validator.

I would say the error is earlier there as well as this line should give an error also:
$validatedData['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

As ericmp said, you first need to retrieve the validateddata to an array and then work with it.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying both, use that $validatedData as an object, so I use it like $validatedData->logo and also try to use it as an array after I convert it and use it like $validatedDataTwo['logo'], it is success tho, but the file path became C:/xampp/tmp/.... on both ways